# Does it make sense to use skip connections in networks with less than ten layers?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, resnet

I was reading about the skip layer connections in the ResNet paper, and how they were beneficial in training very deep networks.

Does it make sense to use such connections in smaller (i.e. AlexNet-like) networks of less than 10 layers?

Comment: One of the main reason you use skip connections is to improve the flow of gradients when the network is deep. The network with skip connections is guaranteed to perform atleast as a plain network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, because their main purpose is on improving *gradient flow* through the network, which in essence increases the capacity without increasing the number of parameters. However, if a small network has enough capacity for your use case, you do not really need more capacity.

Comment: `a1 * x + a0` has the capacity to fit only straight lines `a2 * x^2 + a1 * x + a0` has the capacity to fit only simple curves. If (you think that) the number of parameters in the network are enough to generalize (or fit) the data, then the network is considered to be **capable** of fitting the data and this is what he mentions as the capacity